# square of an integral less than integral of a square

Tags: calculus

Is the following Proposition true, and how would you prove the it?

$\textbf{Proposition.}\textit{ Let }I\textit{ be a real interval, finite or infinite, and let }f(x)\textit{ and }g(x)\textit{ be positive on }I\textit{ and such that }\int_I f^2(x)dx\textit{, }\int_I g^2(x)dx\textit{ and }\int_I f(x)g(x)dx\textit{ all converge. Then, the following is true.}\\
$

$$
\left(
\int\limits_I f(x)g(x)dx
\right)^2
\leqslant
\int\limits_I f^2(x)dx
\int\limits_I g^2(y)dy
$$

I can prove the Proposition by interpreting all the integrals as Riemannian sums with equipartitioned $I$ as follows, but this is not always justified I fear.

\begin{align*}
\left(\sum f_n g_n\right)^2 &\leqslant \left(\sum f_n^2\right) \left(\sum g_k^2\right)\\
\left(\sum f_n g_n\right) \left(\sum f_k g_k\right) &\leqslant \left(\sum f_n^2\right) \left(\sum g_k^2\right)\\
\sum f_n f_k g_n g_k &\leqslant \sum f_n^2 g_k^2\\
\sum f_n g_k \left( f_k g_n-f_n g_k \right) &= -S \leqslant 0
\end{align*}

Indices $n$ and $k$ are dummy, so interchange $n\leftrightarrow k$.

$$
\sum f_k g_n \left(
f_k g_n-f_n g_k
\right)
=S
$$

Subtract the last two inequalities.

$$
\sum \left(
f_k g_n-f_n g_k
\right) \left(
f_k g_n-f_n g_k
\right)
=
\sum \left(
f_k g_n-f_n g_k
\right)^2
=
2S
$$

Since the sum of squares is always positive, this proves the Proposition after taking the limits $n\to\infty$, $k\to\infty$, since the result holds in general.

I don't know if this is justified, even though all the integrands involved are absolutely integrable, or even $L^2$.

So how would you go about proving the Proposition? Is there a more elegant or shorter way to prove it?

Comment: looks like a cauchy-schwarz to me! how do you usually prove that?

Comment: Do you know Hölder's inequality?

Comment: Is direct by Hölders inequality taken $p=q=2$

Comment: ZAF and beelal, you are both right! Who will promote their comment to an answer, please? So I can check it. Both Cauchy-Schwarz and H\"{o}lder do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go back to Riemann sums, this result is actually the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and it yields from observing that the second-order polynomial in $\lambda$
$$\int_I (f+\lambda g)^2$$
is always positive, hence that its discriminant must be non-positive.